# Do I need a visa to leave the Amsterdam airport enroute to Norway from US?

Tags: us-citizens, layovers, amsterdam

I am a US citizen with a valid passport.  I am traveling to Norway via Amsterdam.  I will have a long layover in Amsterdam and would like to leave the airport.  Can I do so without a visa?  If I need a visa, what kind?

Comment: Work or pleasure? Will likely have to go thru Customs heading out, and then Security back in. How long is the layover?

Comment: You can leave the airport without a visa. In fact you will have to in order to enter the Schengen Area.

Answer (score 9):

Amsterdam is in the Schengen area, and as a US citizen you can enter the Schengen area for short visits (of up to 90 days of any 180) without having a visa.

This is the same rule that allows you to go to *Norway* without a visa, as Norway is also in the Schengen area.

(In fact, no matter whether you leave the airport or not, you will pass through the common Schengen immigration point in Amsterdam, and will not pass through immigration when you arrive in Norway).

Comment: Beat me by 26 seconds

Answer (score 2):

You will be stamped into the Schengen Area *in Amsterdam*. Except if you hit a sporadic spot check, that's your last encounter with passport control, whether you stay in the airport or go into town.

Comment: It will be the last encounter with passport control until the end of the trip (or until the first departure from a Schengen country to a non-Schengen country if that happens before the end of the trip).  It's a bit of a nitpick, I know, but people are sometimes surprised when they encounter exit control on leaving the Schengen area.